# jQuery events for both desktop and mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I'm doing a fully responsive page and got to the jQuery part. My question is how to do events that cover both mobile and desktop usage. I have looked in jQuery 1.11.1 file and found no trace of "touch". I figure that I could use `mousedown`as a start. What is best practice when it comes to this?

```
$('.touch-me').on('mousedown, click', function () {
    console.log('touch me');
});
```

Comment: *"I have looked in jQuery 1.11.1 file and found no trace of "touch"."* But if you look in the latest `jquery.mobile.1.4.3.js` (you tagged your question `jquery-mobile`), you'll find it all over. In anycase, `touch` != `mousedown`.

Comment: This works on desktop and mobile units:    $(document).on('click', '#someid', function(e){
        //handle
    });

Comment: yea figure that much. I was looking to not use it. Not that I mind.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yea I taged it because I knew it would be in Mobile. That was more for "confirm my theory". Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use touchstart:

```
$('.touch-me').on('mousedown touchstart', function () {
    console.log('touch me');
});
```

PS: If you need click event too then use it without separating it with a comma (just a space you need).

Comment: is touchstart a valid event in jQuery or does it require jQuery Mobile?

Comment: you need jQuery Mobile

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way if you like:

```
var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
var ev = mobile ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
$('.touch-me').on(ev, function () {
   console.log('touch me');
});
```

Comment: went with query mobile. +1 for this

Comment: Oh of cause, I see that now. Nice solution. Is there any benefit of using this?

Comment: @Dejan.S This code just check browser if it is mobile or desktop and in my code touchstart will work because in mobile mousedown is unknown and vice-versa...